# Is present continuous a valid solution

Tags: future-constructions

If you need to contact me sometimes next week ,I am staying in the Odon hotel in Caen

Can I use present continuous. I know will be staying would be  better as the arrangement has already been made

Comment: What do you think might be wrong? It looks good to me. Could also use "... I will be staying in/at ...". Do not use "sometimes", use the singluar "sometime".

Comment: The cited "Present tense reference to Future" is syntactically fine - but idiomatically, I think competent native speakers are more *likely* to use the explicit future *I **will be** staying in the Odon hotel* in this exact context. That's because we tend to use the *We're doing it tomorrow* form when the "planned future" is relevant to our *current* state, but in this case there's no particular connection to time of utterance. Indeed, we're specifically invited to concentrate only on the hypothetical future (***If*** you need me). Nothing to do with the speaker's *current* circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

> (1) If you need to contact me, I am staying in the Odon hotel in Caen.

The form (1) pretty clearly implies that the speaker is currently staying in the Odon hotel, and will stay there for an indefinite or at least unspecified time.

> (2) If you need to contact me next week, I am staying in the Odon hotel in Caen.

Sentence (2) implies that the speaker will be staying in the Odon for all of next week. It does not indicate whether the speaker is already there or not.

> (2A) If you need to contact me, I am staying in the Odon hotel in Caen next week.

Sentence (2A) carries much the same meaning as (2), but limits the tiem of stay, not the time of desire for contact. This difference is a mater of style, but may suggest that the listener may want to contact the speaker after the following week also.

> (3) If you need to contact me next week, I will be staying in the Odon hotel in Caen.

I think that (3) pretty clearly implies that the speker will be at the Odon next week, but is not there at the time of speaking.

> (4) If you need to contact me next week, I am going to be staying in the Odon hotel in Caen.

Sentence (4) has essentially the same meaning as (3), but stresses that the speaker is not at the Odon now.

If the speaker is in fact not at the Odon when speaker, but has firm plans to be there during all of the following week, any of (2), (3), or (4) would be valid and natural. The choice is a matter of style and emphasis. I would favor (3), as it avoids the possible ambiguity of (2), and does not clutter the sentence as (4) does. But (4) might be preferred if the emphasis on the change of residence is desired.

If the plans are not firm, something like one of the following examples could be used:

> (4) If you need to contact me next week, I will probably be staying in the Odon hotel in Caen.

> (5) If you need to contact me next week, I might be staying in the Odon hotel in Caen.

> (6) If you need to contact me next week, I may be staying in the Odon hotel in Caen.

Sentences (4) through (6) show a decreasing level of certainty in the speaker's plans.